# react-dates/react-dates using day picker on mobile causes the keyboard to appear and disappear

Tags: mobile, react-dates

When using react-dates in my app, I've found that on mobile when the user taps a date in the calendar popup it triggers the mobile keyboard to appear and immediately disappear.

I've found that adding `inputmode="none"` to the inputs seems to fix the issue but I can't find anything in the react-dates docs that will allow me to specify an inputmode.

A screen recording of the issue can be found here: https://youtube.com/shorts/p0qXhzMvuag?feature=share

Has anyone else found an alternative solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Solution I found:

The `readOnly` prop still allows for `onClick` functions, so rather than specifying the input mode, I gave the the react-dates component `readOnly={true}`